# Do ceramic salt and pepper shakers need to be immersed in a Mikvah before use?

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath, tevilas-keilim-dipping

Considering that salt and pepper shakers aren't used to eat food with directly, nor are they used to make food, do they have to be immersed in a Mikvah before using if they are ceramic?

Comment: They are used to serve food: salt.

Comment: Is salt considered food? You can't eat it on its own

Comment: Are you asking because of the utility or because of the material? Or are you asking if it's a Sfeik Sefeika?

Comment: @SethJ, nice edit (to the question); thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the Orthodox Union](http://www.oukosher.org/index.php/common/article/tevilas_keilim_a_primer/), [`kashrut.com`](http://www.kashrut.com/articles/tevilas_keilim/), and [`askmoses.com`](http://www.askmoses.com/en/article/229,89210/Which-food-utensils-must-be-immersed-in-the-Mikvah.html), a saltshaker needs immersion, and that need is definite enough that we say the *b'racha* on the immersion. However, that's assuming it's of metal (or glass). According to those pages, unglazed ceramic/earthenware does not require immersion and glazed ceramic (porcelain) requires immersion, but without saying the *b'racha* on the *mitzva* of immersion; but I know some don't require immersion for porcelain. As always, contact your rabbi for practical advice.

Comment: http://www.dinonline.org/2010/03/16/tevilas-kelim-saltshaker/